# Simple StringBuilder constructor/method issue

Tags: java

I got a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for `setCharAt(int index, char ch)`:

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(4);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    word.setCharAt(i,'-');
```

`StringBuilder(int capacity)`: *Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity specified by the capacity argument.*

`setCharAt(int index, char ch)`: *The character at the specified index is set to ch.*

The only thing I can think of is that no memory was allocated, but then what's the point of `StringBuilder(int capacity)`?

Comment: Here's [some discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3184277/778118) of the purpose of the _capacity_ argument/constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The only thing I can think of is that no memory was allocated, but then what's the point of StringBuilder(int capacity)?

The point is to provide an up front opportunity to allocate a sufficiently large chunk of memory to handle all the data that will be inserted. When the capacity is exceeded, internally a new chunk of memory will have to be allocated and all the values from the old memory copied over. As you can imagine, this could be a performance burden if it occurs a multitude of times.

The behavior is not really odd or unexpected, in fact it is quite consistent with the practice of encapsulation.

What would `ArrayList` do? An `ArrayList` is backed by an array, and using a sufficient initial capacity is more performant, however doing so still does not allow arbitrary access to indices of the array.

I think the odd behavior is thinking of a `StringBuilder` as a representation of a `char[]`. The representation is properly encapsulated at it is, don't poke at it in curious ways.

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`StringBuilder.append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.Object%29)

The constructor you're using does nothing to put data in the StringBuilder.

It only specifies a practical size for the StringBuilder (which I *believe* is for performance).

Until you actually put stuff in the StringBuilder, your code will throw Exceptions.

Note that the documentation you've quoted says this explicitly:

> > "*Constructs a string builder with* **NO CHARACTERS** *in it...*"

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing. I was just wondering what the constructor actually does, if not allocate any memory?  I understand that no characters are in, but why does there need to be any?

Comment: I suggest reading the source code to find out.  I believe that the capacity is primarily used internally for performance (as the StringBuilder grows), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a bit of an odd behavior in `StringBuilder`.

In `AbstractStringBuilder` (which it inherits), the constructor is defined as:

```
AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) {
    value = new char[capacity];
}
```

However, when using `setCharAt()`, we check `count` instead:

```
public void setCharAt(int index, char ch) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    value[index] = ch;
}
```

So, since we didn't set `count` by using the initial constructor, we have an error thrown in our faces.

`count` is redefined in `append()`, `replace()`, `insert()`, and `setLength()`. You could [solve your problem by also calling `setLength(4)`](http://ideone.com/ZfmUyF); however, [as @jahroy pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994922/1438733), it is simpler to just use `append()`.

*Relevant source codes: [`StringBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java), [`AbstractStringBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java)*

Comment: I've never looked at the source, but I assumed it looked something like that, which is why I was so confused when I got the exception.

Comment: @SteveP. Yeah... Technically, it *should* let you. But instead of checking `value.length`, it checks `count` which wasn't updated. It's hard to actually say if this is by design or not.

Comment: @Eric I would like to down vote you comment. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16994970/122207

Comment: @TimBender I won't stop you from any kind of voting. The array is still encapsulated, regardless of the functions we call on the `StringBuilder`. If we were manipulating the array directly, I'd say you had a point. But we're not.

Comment: There is no downvoting comments ;) The answer is good. It walks through the code somewhat and reaffirms why an exception is being thrown. I just think your perspective on whether or not `capacity` is more valid than `count` is wrong.

Comment: @TimBender (I know. :P) I would say, though, that if I *manually* set a capacity, it should allow me to manipulate that data how I see fit. In the case of the default constructor, it allocates 16 blocks in array, but I should not be able to access them. In terms of the explicit setting of the capacity, though, I think that's different. (Being forced to call `setLength()` isn't so bad though, I guess.)

Comment: Yes! There is a question of intent. If one sets a high capacity, one intends to have enough room to avoid a potentially expensive grow operation. If one sets a length, then it is intended to interact the data up to the specified length.

Comment: Maybe they should just change the name of the argument from _capacity_ to _growFactor_ (or something more appropriate)... It's funny how important names can be.

Comment: @jahroy I agree completely.

Comment: @jahroy Curiously enough, a variant of `Vector`'s constructor actually includes a separate `growFactor` arg. I think the overloaded constructor was abandoned for being unnecessarily fine grained.