# Difference between length() and capacity() methods in StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I was trying to figure out when to use or why `capacity()` method is different from `length()` method of `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` classes.

I have searched on Stack Overflow and managed to come up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184244/stringbuilder-capacity) answer, but I didn't understand its distinction with `length()` method. I have visited [this](http://java.meritcampus.com/core-java-topics/java-stringbuffer-length-and-capacity-methods) website also but this helped me even less.

Comment: `length()` is how much stuff is currently in it. `cacacity()` is how much it currently has space for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is for building up text. Internally, it uses an array of characters to hold the text you add to it. `capacity` is the size of the array. `length` is how much of that array is currently filled by text that should be used. So with:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
sb.append("testing");
```

`capacity()` is 1000 (there's room for 1000 characters before the internal array needs to be replaced with a larger one), and `length()` is 7 (there are seven meaningful characters in the array).

The capacity is important because if you try to add more text to the `StringBuilder` than it has capacity for, it has to allocate a new, larger buffer and copy the content to it, which has memory use and performance implications*. For instance, the default capacity of a `StringBuilder` is currently 16 characters (it isn't documented and could change), so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Singing:");
sb.append("I am the very model of a modern Major General");
```

...creates a `StringBuilder` with a `char[16]`, copies `"Singing:"` into that array, and then has to create a **new** array and copy the contents to it before it can add the second string, because it doesn't have enough room to add the second string.

---

* *(whether either **matters** depends on what the code is doing)*

Answer (score 3):

The length of the string is always less than or equal to the capacity of the builder. The length is the **actual size** of the string stored in the builder, and the capacity is the **maximum size** that it can currently fit.

The builder’s capacity is automatically increased if more characters are added to exceed its capacity. Internally, a string builder is an array of characters, so the builder’s capacity is the size of the array. If the builder’s capacity is exceeded, the array is replaced by a new array. The new array size is `2 * (the previous array size + 1)`.

Since you are new to Java, I would suggest you this tip also regarding StringBuilder's efficiency:

You can use `newStringBuilder(initialCapacity)` to create a StringBuilder with a specified initial capacity. By carefully choosing the initial capacity, you can make your program more efficient. If the capacity is always larger than the actual length of the builder, the JVM will never need to reallocate memory for the builder. On the other hand, if the capacity is too large, you will waste memory space. You can use the `trimToSize()` method to reduce the capacity to the actual size.

I tried to explain it the best terms I could so I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Sir(@tripleee) with due respect I would like to ask about the edit which you made to my answer(edit was good), that you changed **current size** to **maximum size**? It can be increased isn't it so **current** is good option?

Comment: I thought it was a useful clarification but if you disagree and already changed it, that's completely fine by me. To me, "actual size" and "current size" seem like de facto synonyms in this context. Maybe "maximum size that it can currently fit" would be a reasonable compromise? The somewhat gratuitous boldfacing might be throwing me off, too.